# why can't I use grouping functions without group by?

Tags: sql, oracle

In the following code, why can't I use count (*) for each row in the table? The count(*) must return the number of colours of each row, which all become one, but it does not. If I use `group by`, it will.

```
select colour,count(*) 
from bricks;
```

**updated:**
another example:

```
select b.*,
(select count(*) from bricks where colour=b.colour)
from bricks b;
```

The above example used grouping function without group by and it works without any errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's just the way SQL demands it. You can't select a discrete column and and aggregate function without listing the discrete columns in a group by statement.

Your second example runs a subquery for each record returned from the main bricks query. This won't perform as well as the first query using a group by.

And you best alias your subquery table - I've seen circumstances where the parser decides you're essentially saying b.colour = b.colour, which will give you the same count(*) for each record in bricks.

Comment: Thanks but b.colour = b.colour gives 6 for all records

Comment: That's the issue I'm highlighting. Without explicit qualification, that may be what your query decides to resolve.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have those bricks, but - I do have Scott's sample `EMP` table with jobs instead.

This is what you tried (and it doesn't work):

```
SQL> select job, count(*)
  2  from emp
  3  order by 1, 2;
select job, count(*)
       *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00937: not a single-group group function
```

This is what works, but - that's not what you want:

```
SQL> select job, count(*)
  2  from emp
  3  group by job
  4  order by 1, 2;

JOB         COUNT(*)
--------- ----------
ANALYST            2
CLERK              4
MANAGER            3
PRESIDENT          1
SALESMAN           4
```

This is what you want (and it works), but - doesn't look pretty:

```
SQL> select e.job,
  2    (select count(*) from emp a where a.job = e.job) cnt
  3  from emp e
  4  order by 1, 2;

JOB              CNT
--------- ----------
ANALYST            2
ANALYST            2
CLERK              4
CLERK              4
CLERK              4
CLERK              4
MANAGER            3
MANAGER            3
MANAGER            3
PRESIDENT          1
SALESMAN           4
SALESMAN           4
SALESMAN           4
SALESMAN           4

14 rows selected.
```

Good news for you - use `count` function in its **analytic** form:

```
SQL> select job, count(*) over (partition by job order by null) cnt
  2  from emp
  3  order by 1, 2;

JOB              CNT
--------- ----------
ANALYST            2
ANALYST            2
CLERK              4
CLERK              4
CLERK              4
CLERK              4
MANAGER            3
MANAGER            3
MANAGER            3
PRESIDENT          1
SALESMAN           4
SALESMAN           4
SALESMAN           4
SALESMAN           4

14 rows selected.

SQL>
```